# operand preceding > has invalid type

Tags: ampl, glpk

I've this variable:

```
var produced{L, M} >= 0;
```

I'm trying to find how many values inside `produced`are larger than 0:

```
subject to fee_calc {m in M} :
    fee[m] = sum {l in L} (if produced[l,m] > 0 then 1 else 0);
```

But it throws this error: "operand preceding > has invalid type"...

How do I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AMPL supports variables in `if-then-else` statements and in expressions involving strict relational operators like `>` and you can solve such problems with a constraint programming solver. See [“LOGIC” AND CONSTRAINT PROGRAMMING EXTENSIONS](http://www.ampl.com/NEW/LOGIC/) for more details.

As for the error, it is likely to be caused by limitations of GLPK, which only supports a subset of AMPL features.